# Simple idiom to break an n-long list into k-long chunks, when n % k > 0?

Tags: python, python-itertools, map-function

In Python, it is easy to break an *n*-long list into *k*-size chunks if *n* is a multiple of *k* (IOW, `n % k == 0`).  Here's my favorite approach (straight from the [**docs**](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#zip)):

```
>>> k = 3
>>> n = 5 * k
>>> x = range(k * 5)
>>> zip(*[iter(x)] * k)
[(0, 1, 2), (3, 4, 5), (6, 7, 8), (9, 10, 11), (12, 13, 14)]
```

(The trick is that `[iter(x)] * k` produces a list of *k* references to *the same iterator*, as returned by `iter(x)`.  Then `zip` generates each chunk by calling each of the *k* copies of the iterator exactly once.  The `*` before `[iter(x)] * k` is necessary because `zip` expects to receive its arguments as "separate" iterators, rather than a list of them.)

The main shortcoming I see with this idiom is that, when *n* is not a multiple of *k* (IOW, `n % k > 0`), the left over entries are just left out; e.g.:

```
>>> zip(*[iter(x)] * (k + 1))
[(0, 1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6, 7), (8, 9, 10, 11)]
```

There's an alternative idiom that is slightly longer to type, produces the same result as the one above when `n % k == 0`, and has a more acceptable behavior when `n % k > 0`:

```
>>> map(None, *[iter(x)] * k)
[(0, 1, 2), (3, 4, 5), (6, 7, 8), (9, 10, 11), (12, 13, 14)]
>>> map(None, *[iter(x)] * (k + 1))
[(0, 1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6, 7), (8, 9, 10, 11), (12, 13, 14, None)]
```

At least, here the left over entries are retained, but the last chunk gets padded with `None`.  If one just wants a different value for the padding, then [`itertools.izip_longest`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest) solves the problem.

But suppose the desired solution is one in which the last chunk is left unpadded, i.e.

```
[(0, 1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6, 7), (8, 9, 10, 11), (12, 13, 14)]
```

Is there a *simple* way to modify the `map(None, *[iter(x)]*k)` idiom to produce this result?

(Granted, it is not difficult to solve this problem by writing a function (see, for example, the many fine replies to [How do you split a list into evenly sized chunks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312443/how-do-you-split-a-list-into-evenly-sized-chunks-in-python) or [What is the most "pythonic" way to iterate over a list in chunks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/434287/what-is-the-most-pythonic-way-to-iterate-over-a-list-in-chunks)).  Therefore, a more accurate title for this question would be "How to salvage the `map(None, *[iter(x)]*k)` idiom?", but I think it would baffle a lot of readers.)

I was struck by how easy it is to break a list into even-sized chunks, and how difficult (*in comparison!*) it is to get rid of the unwanted padding, even though the two problems seem of comparable complexity.

Comment: Are you asking this a practical reason, or just to see whether it can be done?

Comment: Isn't this a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/312443/how-do-you-split-a-list-into-evenly-sized-chunks-in-python ?

Comment: @Ned Batchelder: I tried to make clear that this post was a follow-up/extension thereof (in fact, I cite the same stackoverflow post at the end).  Also, as I tried to explain at the end of this post, this post is less about solving the chunking problem (good solutions to it are given in the posts I cited), but rather to find out if there was a simple way to extend the usefulness of a particular Python idiom.  Maybe the posts needs a different title, but all the ones I could think of looked confusing...

Comment: But since we can write a function to do this and the idiom is decidedly non-obvious, why do you want this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
[x[i:i+k] for i in range(0,n,k)]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
sentinal = object()
split = ( 
    (v for v in r if v is not sentinal) for r in
    izip_longest(*[iter(x)]*n, fillvalue=sentinal))
```

Of course, the better idiom is to call a function as that'll be more readable then anything that'll do the same thing.

Answer (score 3):

from IPython's source:

```
def chop(seq,size):
    """Chop a sequence into chunks of the given size."""
    chunk = lambda i: seq[i:i+size]
    return map(chunk,xrange(0,len(seq),size))
```

The last list returned will have fewer than `chunk` elements if the sequence isn't evenly divisible, basically it gets the short end of the stick but without complaining.

```
>>> chop(range(12),3)
[[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11]]
>>> chop(range(12),4)
[[0, 1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6, 7], [8, 9, 10, 11]]
>>> chop(range(12),5)
[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [10, 11]]
>>> chop(range(12),6)
[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]]
```

Answer (score 1):

What about this? It's a different idiom, but produces your desired result:

```
[x[i:i+k] for i in range(0,len(x),k)] #=> [[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11], [12, 13, 14]]
[x[i:i+k] for i in range(0,len(x),k)] #=> [[0, 1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6, 7], [8, 9, 10, 11], [12, 13, 14]]
```

Or if you really need tuples, use `tuple(x[i:i+k])` instead of just `x[i:i+k]`.